# Filtering Posts greater than certain number of likes

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a question about filtering Posts by Like count greater than a given number.

What I want to achieve is on DJANGO SHELL when I type post.likes is greater than 10 I want to see all posts with more than 10 likes.

How can I do that?

Thanks

```
models.py

class Post(models.Model,HitCountMixin):
  likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes", blank=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a [**`.annotate()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and then [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.annotate(
    nlikes=Count('likes')
).filter(
    nlikes__gt=10
)
```

as of [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), we can replace the `.annotate(…)` with [**`.alias()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Post.objects.alias(
    nlikes=Count('likes')
).filter(
    nlikes__gt=10
)
```